# React native stylesheet multiple values in css statement

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I think this question is best described by an example:

let's say I want to apply margin to an element like this:

```
const myView = () => <View style={styles.viewStyle}></View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewStyle: {
    margin: "0 0 5 10",
  },
})
```

Is it possible to do this without multiple margin statements? 
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can unless you write a function to do something like that.
Like this:

```js
const CommonStyle = {
   margin: (t, r, b, l) => {
        marginTop: t,
        marginRight: r,
        marginBottom: b,
        marginLeft: l,
   }
}
```

Then in your style:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewStyle: {
    ...CommonStyle.margin(0, 0, 5, 10),
  },
})
```

But, in the most common case, we atmost only change margin for 2 directions. And there are serveral options to quickly styling your component when you get used to styling.
Example:

"5 10 5 10" is equal to

```js
{
  marginVertical: 5,
  marginHorizontal: 10,
}
```

"0 0 0 5" is equal to

```js
{
  margin: 0,
  marginLeft: 5,
}
```